# How to write a python program that read the input and convert it to pre-defined 14-segments characters with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have written the turtle graphics functions that define the fourteen segments, and the functions that assemble these segments to form characters, e.g.

```
def MethodA (width) :
   top_stroke(width)    
   middle_stroke(width) 
   left_stroke 
   right_stroke(width)
```

I have all the definitions ready, but how do I let python to read an input and convert the characters of the input into the fourteen segments forms, which I defined previously?

Idealy, if I enter "Pizza", the program should produce the output of the characters 'PIZZA' in the fourteen-segments form.

Any suggestions are welcomed and appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a dictionary with function references like this:

```
Characters = {
    'A': MethodA,
    'B': MethodB,
    # ...
}
```

Then, for a string `s`:

```
s = "Pizza"
for c in s:
    c = c.upper() # to fold lowercase into upper case
    if c in Characters:
        Characters[c](width)
```

This code works using `Characters[c]` to look up the function reference in the dictionary, then the `(width)` causes the function to be called (with a `width` parameter, as the function expects).